# How can I find numerical solutions of discrete SIR model in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, modeling, stability

I was looking to simulate the discrete sir model in MATLAB and also to find stability and bifurcation graph. can anyone help me solve these problems?

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to SO.  Please keep your questions as narrow as possible, and preferably showing what you have already tried that didn't work.  That way you might get help.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A great source for Matlab scripts is the Mathworks file exchange.  A search for the SIR model found:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/75100-sir-epidemic-spread-model?s_tid=srchtitle

This should have what you're looking for (unfortunately don't have Matlab on this computer to check).

For the discrete sir equations a for loop as described in:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/325773-solving-difference-equation-with-its-initial-conditions

should be able to solve your system for fixed parameters.  You're going have to do a bit of work to get the bifurcation diagram and stability.  This answer:

[Generate bifurcation diagram for 2D system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693525/generate-bifurcation-diagram-for-2d-system)

should get you going.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful for SIR model for system of ODE. But in the case of discrete SIR model, I have to deal with system of difference equations. And to analyze the dynamics of discrete SIR model, things gonna change I guess. But I'm not finding any clue how to change and what to change.